# How do you add numpy subarrays to each other?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have used the `numpy.array_split()` function in order to split an array of astronomical data into a series of subarrays of known length (the number of subarrays being completely unknown and arbitrary). I wanted to add these arrays to each other in sequence, so that one array with several subarrays:

```
A = [[1,  2,   3,  4]
     [5,  6,   7,  8]
     [9, 10,  11]]
```

could become this one:

```
B = [15, 18, 21, NaN]
```

I was thinking that it may have been possible to do something like `B = numpy.sum(A[1], A[2], A[3], axis=0)`, and then perform whatever manipulations I might like with B. However, since the number of subarrays is arbitrary, this method would not work unless I knew the number of subarrays.

Any help in resolving this question would be appreciated.

Comment: That `A` can't be "one array with several subarrays". What is it? A list of lists? A list of arrays? Multiple arrays that for some reason you've presented as one?

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably just pad the last member of `A`:

```
>>> a = np.arange(1,12)
>>> A = np.array_split(a,3)
>>> A
[array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([5, 6, 7, 8]), array([ 9, 10, 11])]
>>> A[-1] = np.append(A[-1], [np.nan]*(len(A[-2])-len(A[-1])))
>>> A
[array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([5, 6, 7, 8]), array([  9.,  10.,  11.,  nan])]
>>> np.sum(A,axis=0)
array([ 15.,  18.,  21.,  nan])
```

But to be honest, I think you'll be better off padding and then reshaping, so that you're still working with `numpy` arrays instead of lists of arrays.  `numpy` really isn't designed for dealing with series of varying lengths, and it doesn't handle missing data nearly as conveniently as `pandas`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to approach this problem is to pad first, then split.  If you split first, you have to re-pad multiple elements depending on how the split occurred.  For example, splitting `np.arange(1, 11)` by 3 gets you two rows of insufficient length.

If you're doing arithmetic, maybe padding with zeros is more natural than padding with NaN, but I don't know your application, so we can do it either way.  Padding with zeros:

```
a = np.arange(1, 11)
b = 3
pad_length = (b - len(a) % b) % b
a0 = np.pad(a, (0, pad_length), mode='constant')
A0 = np.array_split(a0)
np.sum(A0, axis=0) # array([15, 18, 10, 12])
```

Padding with NaN:

```
aN = np.append(a, [np.nan] * pad_length)
AN = np.array_split(aN)
```